# IOS & Objective C - How to fill a UIPickerView with a list of countries?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am new to iOS Developement ( it's been 2 weeks now), I am developing an iOS app, and I want to fill a `UIPickerView` with a list of countries.

Here is what I've done so far:

1- created the picker view

2- defined my view controller as a delegate to the picker view

3- added these lines of code to my .m view controller file: (methods: viewdidload, numberOfComponentsInPickerView, titleForRow)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes] count]];

    for (NSString *countryCode in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
    {
        NSString *identifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: countryCode forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode]];
        NSString *country = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey: NSLocaleIdentifier value: identifier];
        [countries addObject: country];
    }
    NSArray *sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;// or the number of vertical "columns" the picker will show...
}
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if (sortedCountries!=nil) {
        return [sortedCountries count];//this will tell the picker how many rows it has - in this case, the size of your loaded array...
    }
    return 0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    //you can also write code here to descide what data to return depending on the component ("column")
    if (sortedCountries!=nil) {
        return [sortedCountries objectAtIndex:row];//assuming the array contains strings..
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Register tab empty?");
    }
    return @"empty";//or nil, depending how protective you are
}
```

and here is my .h file :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RegisterViewController_iPhone : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate> {
    NSArray * sortedCountries;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

@end
```

When I run, it gives me an empty `UIpickerView` ,  I appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Maybe `sortedCountries` is a nil at that point? Just debug it and check or move sorting to `init` and see if it works.

Comment: Change `NSArray *sortedCountries` to just `sortedCountries` in viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
NSArray *sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

You are redifining sortedCountries instead of using the one defined in your header file. Remove `NSArray *`.

Your `viewDidLoad` method should look like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSMutableArray *countries = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: [[NSLocale ISOCountryCodes] count]];

    for (NSString *countryCode in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
    {
        NSString *identifier = [NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: countryCode forKey: NSLocaleCountryCode]];
        NSString *country = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey: NSLocaleIdentifier value: identifier];
        [countries addObject: country];
    }
     sortedCountries = [countries sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

}
```

Comment: Thank you my friend , that was enough to fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma mark - pickerview

-(void)pickerview:(id)sender
{
    pickerView=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,[Util window_height]-260,[Util window_width],300)];
    // pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.75f, 0.75f);
  //  pickerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.85f, 0.85f);
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [pickerView selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
   // [contentView addSubview:pickerView];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{

    return [_items count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
        return[_items objectAtIndex:row];

}

-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    [pickerView removeFromSuperview];
    [Txt_SecurityQue setText:[_items objectAtIndex:row]];
     NSLog(@"Did select");
}


#pragma mark - securityQuestionsArray

-(void)securityQuestionsArray {

    _items =[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
             @"Where do you want to retire?",
             @"Where did you vacation last year?",
             @"What is your personal address",
             @"What is your employer name",
             @"Who is your nearest relative",
             @"What is your best friend phone number",
             @"In what city were you born?",
             @"What was your childhood nickname?",
             @"Type your own question.",
             @"What was the make and model of your first car?",
             @"What time of the day was your first child born?",
             @"What is your oldest sibling’s birthday month and year?",
             @"What was your childhood nickname?",
             @"What is the name of your favorite childhood friend?",
             @"In what city or town did your mother and father meet?",
             @"What is the middle name of your oldest child?",
             @"What is your favorite team?",
             @"What is your favorite movie?",
             @"What was your favorite sport in high school?",
             @"What was your favorite food as a child?",
             @"What is the first name of the boy or girl that you first kissed?",
             @"What was the make and model of your first car?",
             @"What was the name of the hospital where you were born?",
             @"Who is your childhood sports hero?",
             @"What school did you attend for sixth grade?",
             @"What was the last name of your third grade teacher?",
             @"what town was your first job?",
             @"What was the name of the company where you had your first job?",
                          nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I read this line:

```
if (sortedCountries!=nil) {
```

and I see that you are in trouble. Because you are not following Objective-C coding conventions. You have an instance variable named sortedCountries. Instance variables should start with an underscore like _sortedCountries so they can be distinguished from properties. Confusing instance variables and properties is generally causing people problems. So first thing is to change sortedCountries to a property.

In general, I don't put that kind of code into loadView. I write an accessor for sortedCountries like this:

```
- (NSArray*)sortedCountries
{
    if (_sortedCountries == nil)
    {
        .... code to set _sortedCountries to non-nil value
    }

    return _sortedCountries;
}
```

Now if you ever change the sorting order, you just set _sortedCountries to nil and make sure your UI is updated. It also separates the task of creating this list nicely from all the other things that loadView would have to do.

PS. The bit where the trouble hit you was when you also declared a local variable named sortedCountries. That's why these coding conventions are important: Because if you followed coding conventions, it would have been obvious what is wrong in your code.